# PHP Class for mysqli_numrows()

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

I have a PHP class for querying the database like this (I have to keep the copyright on it because i found it on a forum):

```
<?php 

/**
 * Database wrapper for a MySQL with PHP tutorial
 * 
 * @copyright Eran Galperin
 * @license MIT License
 * @see http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/using-php-with-mysql-the-right-way/17
 */
class Db {
// The database connection
protected static $connection;

/**
 * Connect to the database
 * 
 * @return bool false on failure / mysqli MySQLi object instance on success
 */
public function connect() {

    // Try and connect to the database
    if(!isset(self::$connection)) {
        // Load configuration as an array. Use the actual location of your configuration file
        // Put the configuration file outside of the document root
        $config = parse_ini_file('config.ini'); 
        self::$connection = new mysqli('localhost',$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);
    }

    // If connection was not successful, handle the error
    if(self::$connection === false) {
        // Handle error - notify administrator, log to a file, show an error screen, etc.
        return false;
    }
    return self::$connection;
}

/**
 * Query the database
 *
 * @param $query The query string
 * @return mixed The result of the mysqli::query() function
 */
public function query($query) {
    // Connect to the database
    $connection = $this -> connect();

    // Query the database
    $result = $connection -> query($query);

    return $result;
  }

/**
 * Fetch rows from the database (SELECT query)
 *
 * @param $query The query string
 * @return bool False on failure / array Database rows on success
 */
public function select($query) {
    $rows = array();
    $result = $this -> query($query);
    if($result === false) {
        return false;
    }
    while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    return $rows;
}

/**
 * Fetch the last error from the database
 * 
 * @return string Database error message
 */
public function error() {
    $connection = $this -> connect();
    return $connection -> error;
}

/**
 * Quote and escape value for use in a database query
 *
 * @param string $value The value to be quoted and escaped
 * @return string The quoted and escaped string
 */
public function quote($value) {
    $connection = $this -> connect();
    return "'" . $connection -> real_escape_string($value) . "'";
}
 }
```

I accessed the database (i'm not sure if it is the best method but it works) with this:

```
<?PHP
include 'Db.php';
$Db = new Db();
$results = $Db->select("SELECT * FROM users");
$error = $Db->error();
echo $error;

foreach ($results as $value) {
extract($value);
echo $id.'';
echo $username.'';
}
?>
```

Now, my question is: how do I set a specific class or something like that for mysqli_num_rows?

In the non-OOP style i was using that:

```
$nrusers = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if($nrusers !=0)
{
    // something to do
} else {
    // something else to do
}
```

I must specify that, sometimes I need to check if $nrusers !=0 and sometimes $nrusers == 1 etc.

The code should be like that:

```
$results = $Db->select("SELECT * FROM users", "$numrows != 0", "Returned error if $numrows != 0");
```

Other way I guess is (I do not know how to extract numrows from the class):

```
if($nrusers !=0)
{
 foreach ($results as $value) {
    extract($value);
    echo $id.'';
    echo $username.'';
     }
}else{
    // error
}
```

Comment: you want to change the above code in procedural php??

Comment: Before you end up painstakingly writing your own ORM, do have a look at existing ones like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/),
[Propel](http://propelorm.org/), and 
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent) to see if they might do the job you need.

Comment: this class is very bad and you better get rid of it in favor of vanilla mysqli

Comment: nevertheless, as you already have $results array, which you can simply count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a pretty minimal class, and what I find objectionable in it, is that it encourages you to pass in SQL queries as strings, rather than using named parameters.  SQL injection is a major concern, and it provides a method that wraps real_escape_string.  With named parameters, you do not need to escape strings at all, so that makes for better and safer code.

I would highly recommend using one of the ORM's listed in Tadman's comment.   I'd suggest Doctrine because you can use the Database abstraction layer (DBAL) in much the same way that you are trying to use this very old database class.

With that said-----

This is a simple class, and you can either alter it or extend it in a new class. Mysqli [provides this method](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) that can be used to get counts of result set rows for selects or rows changed in SQL DML statements.

Because I don't want to get into OOP, I'm just going to provide a few small alterations that could be done as a subclass, but are just provided as direct changes to the existing class:

```
class Db {
   // The database connection
   protected static $connection;
   // Hold row count
   protected $numrows = 0;
```

In the query method:

```
public function query($query) {
// Connect to the database
$connection = $this -> connect();

// Query the database
$result = $connection -> query($query);

if ($result) {
    $this->numrows = $result->mysqli_affected_rows();
} else {
    $this->numrows = 0;
}

return $result;
```

}

Last but not least, you would need a getter to get the number of rows:

```
   public function getNumRows() {
       return $this->numrows;          
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can probably do what you want by just checking if the `$results` variable is not empty. Like this:

```
<?PHP
include 'Db.php';
$Db = new Db();
$results = $Db->select("SELECT * FROM users");
$error = $Db->error();
echo $error;
if (!empty($results)) {
    foreach ($results as $value) {
        extract($value);
        echo $id.'';
        echo $username.'';
    }
}
?>
```